# Neo4j query all triples fails

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph with 300k nodes and 4M relationships.

I'd like to query all triples:

```
MATCH p=()-[]->()
RETURN p
```

I get the following error:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed

org.neo4j.io.pagecache.CursorException: PropertyRecord claims to have more property blocks than can fit in a record
```

Do you know what goes wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Does it still happen when you restart the DB?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that does not make a difference. It seems a memory problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to export all nodes and relationships into a csv file using APOC function.

Ref: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/csv/

For example; to download all nodes and relationships of Movies database

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.all("movies.csv", {})
```

OR if you want to add your own query, see sample below:

```
MATCH (person:Person)
WHERE person.name STARTS WITH "L"
WITH collect(person) AS people
CALL apoc.export.csv.data(people, [], "movies-l.csv", {})
YIELD file, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize, batches, done, data
RETURN file, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize, batches, done, data
```

==================

Why do you need to see 300k nodes and 8M relationships in one browser?
You can use alternatives below:

```
  1  call db.schema.visualization()  -> a simplified view of the database
    
  2  MATCH p=()-[]->()
    RETURN p
    LIMIT 25     -> limits few nodes to view
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't need to see them.
I get the same error, even if operate the query with the Python API, or in the neo4j console with the bash. It's not a rendering problem. It seems a memory problem. Are you aware of a method to batch a query like that, in a non-parametric way? I would not know in advance what parameters to pass, as the graph is not known a-priori. Anyways, I do need to get the whole graph.

Comment: why do you need to look at 300k nodes and 4M relationships at the same instant? Do you need to download the database into a datafile?

Comment: Yes, I need to download the database and store a representation of the triples (e.g. in a numpy array containing head indexes and tail indexes, or a networkx graph) and run ML experiments on it.